# CodedUi method which checks all cells in certain column

Tags: c#

I have the following extension method which checks all cells for values in a table column with the specified header name:

```
public static bool AllCellsInColumnHaveValue(this HtmlTable table, string columnName)
{
    // Find the columnindex of the specified column name
    var cell = new HtmlHeaderCell(table);
    cell.SearchProperties.Add(new PropertyExpression
        (UITestControl.PropertyNames.FriendlyName, columnName, PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains));
    var columnIndex = cell.ColumnIndex;

    // Check all cells in the column if they have a value
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var tableCells = row.GetChildren();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tableCells[columnIndex].FriendlyName))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // If we get here all rows in the column contain a value
    return true;
}
```

Is there a way to improve this method?

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: Never done this UITestControl stuff

**Edge case**

If the searched columnName isn't contained in the header of the table I would expect the returned `columnIndex` to be `-1` and therefor the check for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` will throw an exception.

---

<s>Instead of using `row.GetChildren()` and then access the needed cell by index, you should better use the right tool for the job and call the [`GetCell(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.htmlcontrols.htmlrow.getcell.aspx) method.</s>

---

Because an extension method can be also called directly like `AllCellsInColumnHaveValue(aHtmlTable, aColumnName);` you should ensure that the passed in `HtmlTable table`is not null.

---

Comment: The problem is the row is not actually of type `HmlRow` but of type `UiTestControl` so your first suggestion does not work unfortunately. The null check can indeed be included. I will check the column index when not found. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: My fault. If I see `table.Rows` I assume to get some kind of `TableRow`.

Comment: Yeah var is not that clear without IntelliSense. Next time I will type the types. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
// Check all cells in the column if they have a value
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
    var tableCells = row.GetChildren();

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tableCells[columnIndex].FriendlyName))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comments that describe what your code does are, for the most part, unnecessary and should be deleted. Your code (provided it is written well) typically describes what you're doing quite well.

Instead, focus on using your comments to describe *why* you've chosen to code in that way, for times when you've had to code outside of the standard way of doing things.

The exception to this, of course, is when the code you've written is not very understandable. In this case, comments explaining what the code is doing are a good idea (if the code cannot be refactored to make it clearer).

Lastly, it might be wise to also add an argument check for the `columnName` parameter. While it is likely the constructor for `PropertyExpression` will also check the value of `columnName`, it is good practice to check it yourself in case you wish to use the value in some other way later, and to prevent needless execution before the exception is thrown.

Depending on what values are acceptable, this will probably help:

```
public static bool AllCellsInColumnHaveValue(this HtmlTable table, string columnName)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Argument must not be null or the empty string.", "columnName");
    }
```